# Should I write `.registration = true` for an "external" DLL in a R package?

Tags: r, dll, package

When I do a package including some C code or using **Rcpp**, I type the roxygen code:

```
#' @useDynLib TheDLL, .registration=true
```

I did a package in which I included some DLLs created with Haskell, that I put in the **inst/libs** folder. I didn't type `.registration=true` in the roxygen code and the package works fine. Should I type it nevertheless? If so, what is the role of `.registration=true`?

Answer (score 2):

I think you almost certainly shouldn't use it in a general-purpose DLL, but if the DLL was written specifically for R, maybe you should.  It indicates that the dll calls `R_registerRoutines` from its `R_init_DLLNAME` function, so entry points can be saved into variables.  For example, you might have a function named "foo".  You can call it using

```
.Call("foo", ...)
```

without registering it, and R will need to search symbol tables for it at run time.  Or you can register it and call it as

```
.Call(foo, ...)
```

and the search is unnecessary.  This is discussed mainly in section 5.4.2 of ["Writing R Extensions"](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html).  I believe that if you specify `.registration=true` then R will use the registration information to find entry points, otherwise it needs to search through all the exports of the DLL, which is probably slower.

Comment: Thanks. I use `.C`, not `.Call`. I tried and this works, so I will put it.